# Pandas DataFrame pivot (reshape?)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

I can't seem to get this right... here's what I'm trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'item_id': [1,1,3,3,3],
    'contributor_id': [1,2,1,4,5],
    'contributor_role': ['sing', 'laugh', 'laugh', 'sing', 'sing'],
    'metric_1': [80, 90, 100, 92, 50],
    'metric_2': [180, 190, 200, 192, 150]
})

--->

   item_id contributor_id contributor_role   metric_1  metric_2  
0     1          1             sing              80       180  
1     1          2             laugh             90       190  
2     3          1             laugh             100      200  
3     3          4             sing              92       192  
4     3          5             sing              50       150
```

And I want to reshape it into:

```
     item_id        SING_1_contributor_id SING_1_metric_1 SING_1_metric_2  SING_2_contributor_id SING_2_metric_1 SING_2_metric_2 ... LAUGH_1_contributor_id LAUGH_1_metric_1 LAUGH_1_metric_2 ... <LAUGH_2_...>

0       1               1                 80              180                   N/A                N/A              N/A      ...          2                    90           190 ... N/A..

1       3               4                 92              192                   5                  50               150      ...          1                    100          200 ... N/A..
```

Basically, for each item_id, I want to collect all relevant data into a single row.  Each item could have multiple types of contributors, and there is a max for each type (e.g. max SING contributor = A per item, max LAUGH contributor = B per item). There are a set of metrics tied to each contributor (but for the same contributor, the values could be different across different items / contributor types).

I can probably achieve this through some seemingly inefficient methods (e.g. looping and matching then populating a template df), but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve this, potentially through cleverly specifying the `index` / `values` / `columns` in the pivot operation (or any other method..).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

EDIT:

Ended up adapting Ben's script below into the following:

```
df['role_count'] = df.groupby(['item_id', 'contributor_role']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df['contributor_role'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['contributor_role'] + '_' + row['role_count'], axis=1)
df = df.set_index(['item_id','contributor_role']).unstack()
df.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in df.columns.values]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the additional key with `cumcount` then do `unstack`

```
df['newkey']=df.groupby('item_id').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df['contributor_id']=df['contributor_id'].astype(str)
s = df.set_index(['item_id','newkey']).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)
s
Out[38]: 
        contributor_id_1 contributor_role_1  ...  metric_1_3  metric_2_3
item_id                                      ...                        
1                      1               sing  ...         NaN         NaN
3                      1         messaround  ...        50.0       150.0
```

Comment: Hey Ben! This looks very promising! Is there is a way to move the `contributor_role` information also into the columns names? So we have columns like `SING_1_contributor_id`,  `SING_1_metric_1`...?

Comment: hmm, still not quite exact, but it was helpful enough for me to figure out the rest, See my edit for the eventual script I've ended up using. Thank you!